# Changing Name on API Keys

Tags: facebook, api, key, facebook-social-plugins, api-key

Over a year ago, I created API keys to use the Facebook Like and Share buttons for our website. Since that time, our corporate name changed.

The problem is that our old name shows up when people use these web tools (ie: "via ...").

Is there a way to update the name associated with our API key? Or do I have to setup a whole separate account?

Comment: please write your website's link, i think you should change og's
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that we're using XFBML, not OG for this. I know I can request a new key, but it'd be a hassle to update it everywhere.

Comment: can you give me your website's url?

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure it's the app name you need to change, this is done from https://developers.facebook.com/apps by an admin of the app

It might also be the 'site name' which is being displayed on the Like and Share stories, this should be one of the meta tags on your page, so change that and Facebook's cache will clear, or can be manually cleared by running the URL through https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug